# jquery ui slider: how to change the position of slider only programmatically?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slider

I use jQuery UI Slider element and I want to change the position of slider without user's action - only by code. is there any case to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the value option of the slider. This example sets the initial value to 50 on a scale of 0 to 100 then moves it to 25 after a three second delay:

```
$('#slider').slider({
    max: 100,
    min: 0,
    value: 50,
    disabled: true
});
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#slider").slider("option", "value", 25);
}, 3000);​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/KX3gg/2/)**.

Comment: In you example I can change the position of slider by mouse free.
I need (to be clarify) to have that this action can be executed only by me in code: user click on one object - slider has changed position, next click on another button - slider moved and so on...But no moving the slider by mouse.

Comment: Not a problem, just set the disabled option to true. jsFiddle updated in my answer.